How to use Temporal as a type?
When I try:
const a: Temporal = new Temporal.PlainDate(2024, 2, 1)

I get:
Cannot use namespace 'Temporal' as a type.deno-ts(2709)

What happens? This contrasts with how Date is used:
const b: Date = new Date(2024, 2, 1)


Do not set the type on the right of the variable and infer it from the output of Temporal.PlainDate, like so: const a = Temporal.PlainDate(xxxx). I'm pretty sure it is going to be Temporal.PlainDate as the result.

Temporal is not a type, but a namespace. From Namespaces and Modules:

Namespaces are simply named JavaScript objects in the global namespace.

or from Namespaces:

“Internal modules” are now “namespaces”. “External modules” are now simply “modules”

To fix this, you need to use the correct type Temporal.PlainDate:
const a: Temporal.PlainDate = new Temporal.PlainDate(2024, 2, 1)

